# Jersey: Passing data to a .jsp page

Tags: java, jersey

I'm new to Jersey and Web app development. I've attempted to Google my problem but can't seem to find the correct answer on either Jersey's documentation or the Internet. I've got a complex data type called `User`. This data type contains various Strings and URI's. I'm attempting to pass a variable of this type from a java file to the jsp using the following code...

**.java code**

```
return new Viewable("/page.jsp", User);
```

**.jsp code**

```
<%@System.out.println(request);%>
```

I've tried various variations on the .jsp code that I found on mailing lists but they all seem to return the same error which is...

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /page.jsp (line: 3, column: 7) Invalid directive
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:408)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:89)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:498)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseFileDirectives(Parser.java:1777)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:135)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parseDirectives(ParserController.java:119)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:193)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:644)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:358)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<%@ ... %>` indicates a directive in JSP. For a code snippet (scriptlet), use `<% ... %>`.

Comment: do'h! :) Thanks for the help. Apologies my issue was so trivial, I didn't expect that.

Comment: Nevertheless, the question is interesting. Especially presenting a connection to the expression language would be interesting http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info.

Answer (score 3):

In java file ,you need use like this:

```
request.setAttribute(user);
```

and use in jsp.file:

```
request.getAttribute(user);
```

//you can use request/session/servletContext/application to send information from java file to jsp file.

if you just need use Class User in jsp file,you just do it like this:

```
<@package import="//Class User's URL"> or <jsp:useBean.../>
```

Comment: That doesn't apply to a Jersey and JSP app at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass values from servlet to jsp page using request.setAttribute. That being said, I would suggest **create a class for User and have getter setter methods to attach the values onto the class**.Then **pass Class.id or Class.name or Class.'whichever field' as the parameter inside request**.setAttribute you want to pass to the jsp page.